# Value not available within a private class

Tags: php, class

My php script has two sql statements. The second one (connection 2) is not executing. I believe its because the value for 'id' is not set since it's within a private class. I was wondering if anyone had a suggestion on how to fix this?

```
        <?php
    //process pdf file upload
        if (isset($_FILES["flyer"]["name"])); {
            $allowedExtsf = array("pdf");
            $tempf = explode(".", $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
            $extensionf = end($tempf);
            if (($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] == "application/pdf") && ($_FILES["flyer"]["size"] < 524288000) && in_array($extensionf, $allowedExtsf)) 
            {

                      if (file_exists("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"])) 
                           {
    //if file exists, delete the file on the server
                              unlink("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
                           }
    //move currrent pdf to the flyers folder
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["flyer"]["tmp_name"],"../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
    //Make url of pdf file                  
            $ad_link="http://www.website.com/flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"];

    //SQL statement 1, insert all form fields, file url and current date time
          }
          else {
              $ad_link = NULL;
          }
      require('../dbcon2.php');
    //Connection 1
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO listings (title, address, lot_size, zoning, build_size, sale_price, lease_price, comment, transaction, ad_link, date_added) VALUES (:title, :address, :lot_size, :zoning, :build_size, :sale_price, :lease_price, :comment, :transaction, :ad_link, now())");
    //Bind
          $stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']); 
          $stmt->bindParam(':address', $_POST['address']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':lot_size', $_POST['lot_size']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':zoning', $_POST['zoning']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':build_size', $_POST['build_size']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':sale_price', $_POST['sale_price']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':lease_price', $_POST['lease_price']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':comment', $_POST['comment']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':transaction', $_POST['transaction']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':ad_link', $ad_link);
        $stmt->execute();
        $id = $conn->lastInsertId();
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $lot_size = $_POST['lot_size'];
        $zoning = $_POST['zoning'];
        $build_size = $_POST['build_size'];
        $sale_price = $_POST['sale_price'];
        $lease_price = $_POST['lease_price'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $transaction = $_POST['transaction'];
        $conn = null;
        }
    //Create class
      class CropAvatar {
          private $src;
          private $id;
          private $title;
          private $address;
          private $lot_size;
          private $zoning;
          private $build_size;
          private $sale_price;
          private $lease_price;
          private $comment;
          private $transaction;
          private $data;
          private $file;
          private $dst;
          private $type;
          private $extension;
    //location to save original image
          private $srcDir = '../0images/listimg/orig';
    //location to save cropped image
          private $dstDir = '../0images/listimg/mod';
          private $msg;
    //Add to consttruct
      function __construct($src, $data, $file, $id, $title, $address, $lot_size, $zoning, $build_size, $sale_price, $lease_price, $comment, $transaction) {
          $this -> setSrc($src);
          $this -> setData($data);
          $this -> setFile($file);
          $this -> setId($id);
          $this -> setTitle($title);
          $this -> setAddress($address);
          $this -> setLot_size($lot_size);
          $this -> setZoning($zoning);
          $this -> setBuild_size($build_size);
          $this -> setSale_price($sale_price);
          $this -> setLease_price($lease_price);
          $this -> setComment($comment);
          $this -> setTransaction($transaction);  
          $this -> crop($this -> src, $this -> dst, $this -> data, $this -> lastid, $this -> title, $this -> address, $this -> lot_size, $this -> zoning, $this -> build_size, $this -> sale_price, $this -> lease_price, $this -> comment, $this -> transaction);
      }
              public function setId($id) {
                       $this->id = $id;
      }
              public function setTitle($title) {
                       $this->title = $title;
      }
              public function setAddress($address) {
                       $this->address = $address;
      }
              public function setLot_size($lot_size) {
                       $this->lot_size = $lot_size;
      }
              public function setZoning($zoning) {
                       $this->zoning = $zoning;
      }
              public function setBuild_size($build_size) {
                       $this->build_size = $build_size;
      }
              public function setSale_price($sale_price) {
                       $this->sale_price = $sale_price;
      }
              public function setLease_price($lease_price) {
                       $this->lease_price = $lease_price;
      }
              public function setComment($comment) {
                       $this->comment = $comment;
      }
              public function setTransaction($transaction) {
                       $this->transaction = $transaction;
      }
      //NNEED TO SET THE VARIABLES

              private function setSrc($src) 
              {
                  if (!empty($src)) 
                  {
                      $type = exif_imagetype($src);
                      if ($type) 
                      {
                          $this -> src = $src;
                          $this -> type = $type;
                          $this -> extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                          $this -> setDst();
                      }
                  }
              }
              private function setData($data) 
              {
                  if (!empty($data)) 
                  {
                      $this -> data = json_decode(stripslashes($data));
                  }
              }
              private function setFile($file) 
              {
                  $errorCode = $file['error'];
                  if ($errorCode === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
                  {
                      $type = exif_imagetype($file['tmp_name']);
                      if ($type) 
                      {
                          $dir = $this -> srcDir;
                          if (!file_exists($dir)) 
                          {
                              mkdir($dir, 0777);
                          }
                          $currdate=date('YmdHis');
                          $extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                          $src = $dir . '/' . $currdate . $extension;
                          if ($type == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG || $type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
                              if (file_exists($src)) 
                              {
                                  unlink($src);
                              }
                          $result = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $src);
    //Connection 2 - Update sql row according to row id with the url of cropped image
                          $listing_img="http://www.website.com/0images/listimg/mod/" . $currdate . $extension;
                          $GLOBALS[ 'listing_img' ];
                      require('../dbcon2.php');
                          $GLOBALS[ 'id' ];
                            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                            $sql="UPDATE listings SET listing_img='$listing_img' WHERE id=$this->id";
                            $conn->exec($sql);
                            $conn = null;
    //Error handling
                      if ($result) {
                          $this -> src = $src;
                          $this -> type = $type;
                          $this -> extension = $extension;
                          $this -> setDst();
                      } else {
                           $this -> msg = 'Failed to save image file';
                      }
                  } else {
                      $this -> msg = 'Please upload image with the following types only: JPG, PNG, GIF';
                  }
              } else {
                  $this -> msg = 'Please upload image file';
              }
          } else {
              $this -> msg = $this -> codeToMessage($errorCode);
          }
      }
      private function setDst() {
          $dir = $this -> dstDir;
          if (!file_exists($dir)) {
              mkdir($dir, 0777);
          }
          $this -> dst = $dir . '/' . date('YmdHis') . $this -> extension;
      }
      private function crop($src, $dst, $data) {
          if (!empty($src) && !empty($dst) && !empty($data)) {
              switch ($this -> type) {
                  case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                      $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($src);
                      break;
                  case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                      $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                      break;
                  case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                      $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src);
                      break;
              }
              if (!$src_img) {
                  $this -> msg = "Failed to read the image file";
                  return;
              }
              $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor(220, 220);
              $result = imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $data -> x, $data -> y, 220, 220, $data -> width, $data -> height);
              if ($result) {
                  switch ($this -> type) {
                      case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                          $result = imagegif($dst_img, $dst);
                          break;
                      case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                          $result = imagejpeg($dst_img, $dst);
                          break;
                      case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                          $result = imagepng($dst_img, $dst);
                          break;
                  }
                  if (!$result) {
                      $this -> msg = "Failed to save the cropped image file";
                  }
              } else {
                  $this -> msg = "Failed to crop the image file";
              }
              imagedestroy($src_img);
              imagedestroy($dst_img);
          }
      }
              private function codeToMessage($code) {
                  switch ($code) {
                      case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                          $message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
                          break;
                      case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                          $message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
                          break;
                      case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                          $message = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
                          break;
                      case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                          $message = 'No file was uploaded';
                          break;
                      case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                          $message = 'Missing a temporary folder';
                          break;
                      case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                          $message = 'Failed to write file to disk';
                          break;
                      case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                          $message = 'File upload stopped by extension';
                          break;
                      default:
                          $message = 'Unknown upload error';
                  }
                  return $message;
              }

                      public function getResult() {
                  return !empty($this -> data) ? $this -> dst : $this -> src;
              }
                      public function getMsg() {
                  return $this -> msg;
              }
                      public function getId() {
                  return $this -> id;
              }
                      public function getTitle() {
                  return  $this->title;
              }
                      public function getAddress() {
                  return  $this->address;
              }
                      public function getLot_size() {
                  return  $this->lot_size;
              }
                      public function getZoning() {
                  return   $this->zoning;
              }
                      public function getBuild_size() {
                  return  $this->build_size;
              }
                      public function getSale_price() {
                  return  $this->sale_price;
              }
                      public function getLease_price() {
                  return  $this->lease_price;
              }
                      public function getComment() {
                  return  $this->comment;
              }
                      public function getTransaction() {
                  return  $this->transaction;
              }
          }
                 $crop = new CropAvatar($_POST['avatar_src'], $_POST['avatar_data'], $_FILES['avatar_file'], $id, $title, $address, $lot_size, $zoning, $build_size, $sale_price, $lease_price, $comment, $transaction);
                 $response = array(
              'state'  => 200,
              'message' => $crop -> getMsg(),
              'result' => $crop -> getResult(),
              'id' => $crop -> getId(),
              'title' => $crop -> getTitle(),
              'address' => $crop -> getAddress(),
              'lot_size' => $crop -> getLot_size(),
              'zoning' => $crop -> getZoning(),
              'build_size' => $crop -> getBuild_size(),
              'sale_price' => $crop -> getSale_price(),
              'lease_price' => $crop -> getLease_price(),
              'comment' => $crop -> getComment(),
              'Transaction' => $crop -> getTransaction()
          );
          echo json_encode($response);
    ?>
```

Comment: Try to include on the parts of code relevant to the question.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: That class is quite unnecessarily convolute

Comment: @brenjt <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' in /home/username/public_html/members_area/crop-avatar.php:177
Stack trace:

Comment: *"I believe its because the value for 'id' is not set since it's within a private class."* - What was that theory based on? Have you tested it? And what was the outcome?

Comment: @brenjt this corresponds to the second sql statement

Comment: @GolezTrol yes fatal error at the line corresponding to the second sql statement $conn->exec($sql);

Comment: You forgot to "prepare".

Comment: @Verdolino I've treid to do this, but people end up just asking for the rest of the code to find this bug

Comment: @Fred-ii- Please explain!!!!!!!!!!!! this recurrent issue has been causing me problems for close to a month! i'm groveling

Comment: Example: `$sql = "UPDATE books 
        SET title=?, author=?
  WHERE id=?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title,$author,$id));`

Comment: `$sql="UPDATE listings SET listing_img='$listing_img' WHERE id=$this->id"; 
$q = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$q->exec($sql);` should make it kick in.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm getting <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method PDOStatement::exec() with that

Comment: Try using `execute` instead of `exec`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not joking it's been a month. I don't think i will ever forget 'Prepare' again. Please post as an answer, and I'll mark it. and put in for a SE tip jar link for guys like you. Thank you very much Sir, I'm impressed

Comment: @Rhillz It has been done. Glad to have helped, *cheers* and thanks for the SE tip jar ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't "prepared" your query yet. You simply went from declaring your query, to executing.

```
$sql="UPDATE listings SET listing_img='$listing_img' WHERE id=$this->id"; 
$q = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$q->execute($sql);
```

Plus, I replaced `exec` with `execute`, since that gave you a fatal error.

---

Consult the following for the differences between both:

- [**PDO::exec**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)
- [**PDOStatement::execute**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

---

Footnotes:

As stated in comments below: It is highly suggested that you use placeholders for this query, just as you did for the other one.

- The mere use of the PDO API, doesn't safeguard against SQL injection, therefore you need to use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: Is there reason you don't use placeholders?

Comment: @vp_arth Shouldn't you be asking the OP?

Comment: @vp_arth I do agree with your comment and I've made an edit to that effect, thank you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm trying to figure out more about this out. are sql statements inherently static and is using $this not appropriate because of that?

Comment: @Rhillz It's just for this part `listing_img='$listing_img'`